# Silverstripe - multiple Problems with dynamically generated Forms

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe

I've got a multiple forms on my page to add items to a shopping cart. That worked well until I added 2 dynamically created Dropdownfields to the Form. To fill the Dropdowns I changed

`public function addToCart($title, $price) {}`

to

`public function addToCart($ID) {}`

to check if $ID returns the right value, I putted $ID to the value of a textfield.

That's the code to get all Items and Forms

```
public function getItems() {
   return Item::get();
}
```

In Template

```
    <% loop getItems %>
       ...
        $Top.addToCart($ID)
       ...
    <% end_loop %>
```

if I set $ID to 1 in my function, than everything works like expected but if I use the Data which is returned by my markup, I receive three errors.

1. [Notice] Object of class SS_HTTPRequest could not be converted to int
2. [Warning] mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
3. [Warning] mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

I think error 1 is because of `$item = Item::get()->byID($ID);` and error 2 + 3 is because of the dropdowns.

But why??

Can someone please point me in the right direction?
That's my code http://pastie.org/private/vnepfjt0pi5qehmoyqv1ag

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

To error 1 : I already tried to convert ID to an Integre `$ID = (int)$ID;` but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
[Notice] Object of class SS_HTTPRequest could not be converted to int
```

Is likely thrown by `DataList::byID()` which is expecting a numeric value.

This means that what you think is numeric that comes from `$ID` in your template, isn’t numeric.

Without knowing what the `SS_List` looks like that is generated by `getItems()` I’m only guessing, but I’ll bet if you printed `$ID` in your template, it wouldn’t be a number.

Maybe `getItems()` is supposed to be getting data from an `SS_HTTPRequest` object generated by a user response, and you’re actually using it in the wrong context?

Either look for a similar method to use in a template context (Hint SS methods for us in templates usually begin with a capital letter) or adapt `getItems()` for your own use.

Also, just some tips:

```
$colors = ColorObject::get()->filter(array('ItemID' => $ID));
```

Shouldn’t that be:

```
$colors = ColorObject::get()->filter(array('ID' => $ID));
```

?

```
$colorSource = $colors->map('ID', 'Title’);
```

Is the same as:

```
$colorSource = $colors->map();
```

Good luck, Russ

Comment: hi, getItems() is this 'return Item::get();' it just returns all stored Items. I already tried to convert ID like this $ID = (int)$ID; but with now luck. still the same error. Any Ideas? $colors is correct, because I'd like to get all colors stored for this Item.